# Concatenation Breaks Numbers with Padded Zeros in SQL Server

Tags: sql, string-concatenation, zero-padding

I have some non-working code to concatenate two strings, one of which is a year value and the other is a month value, both of which I convert to strings from integers. The month further needs padded with leading zeros (January is 01, not 1).

So, this is a year-month field, and should read this to reflect January 2020:

```
202001
```

I was able to pad the month to 2 digits using this:

```
LEFT('00'+CAST(a.[Fiscal Month] as varchar(2)),2)) as [YearPeriod]
```

And this works on it's own.  But once I concatenate it with the year, like this,

```
CAST(a.[Fiscal Year] as varchar(4)) + LEFT('00'+CAST(a.[Fiscal Month] as varchar(2)),2) as [Period]
```

Then I end up with no month at all.  All the dates look like this:

```
202000
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I've used various kinds of syntax ("concat" function as opposed to + as well as converting to the string after the padding vs converting first). I also tried padding with only 1 digit of zeros thinking I was cutting off the month number with zeros.

I have been formatting date fields and dealing with this, and I can't move on to the project I need to finish. Is the concatenation canceling out the month field somehow?

The field that this is going into is an `nvarchar(6)`, so in my code I formatted the year portion to nvarchar(4) and the month to nvarchar(2), hoping that would just work being added together. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
convert(varchar(6), a.[Fiscal Year] * 100 + a.[Fiscal Month])
```

Comment: Oh Good Lord, thank you!! Yes it worked.  I would never have thought of that. Clever :)